# How to resolve "Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel" issue on textview click listener?

Tags: java, android, textview, runtimeexception, parcel

I have declared one textview as static as follows:

```
public static TextView abc;
```

It is referenced in onCreateView() of a fragment as follows:

```
abc= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.abc);
```

I am getting the following runtime error in its click listener, only in Vivo phone(Device Name:Vivo XL4, Device Model: Vivo XL4 (V0350WW) (Vivo XL4), OS Version: 8.1.0, SDK Version:Android 3.0.13). Can anybody help me to find out the issue?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:39)
at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:37)
at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init>(InputBindResult.java:68)
at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:112)
at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:110)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus(IInputMethodManager.java:723)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1295)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onPostWindowFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1538)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4058)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6525)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:445)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare `TextView` or other views as static. They are connected to the lifecycle of their Fragment/Activity and cannot be used after the Fragment or Activity has been destroyed.